# How to login using Angular 4? The Theme we are using is uses the fack-bakcend provider concept?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

I am new to Angular 4. I have the basic understanding of the components of the theme we are using. But by default the theme has the fack backend provider.

auth.component.ts

```
signin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.model.username));
            // localStorage.setItem("username", "username");
            this._router.navigate(['http://localhost:9090/index']);
        },
        error => {
            this.showAlert('alertSignin');
            this._alertService.error(error);
            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

authentication.service.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "/login";
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('username', username);
    body.append('password', password);
    // let body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    return this.http.post(url, body);

}
```

login.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="signin()" #f="ngForm" class="m-login__form m-form" action="">
                        <ng-template #alertSignin></ng-template>
                        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                            <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                            <input class="form-control m-input m-login__form-input--last" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row m-login__form-sub">
                            <div class="col m--align-left">
                                <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--focus">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" [(ngModel)]="model.remember" #remember="ngModel">
                                    Remember me
                                    <span></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col m--align-right">
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="m_login_forget_password" class="m-link">
                                    Forget Password ?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="m-login__form-action">
                            <button [disabled]="loading" [ngClass]="{'m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light': loading}" class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air">
                                Sign In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

My code is getting Logged In but not redirected. What I have did wrong in this?

[image: Response of the code after update auth.component.ts and authentication.service.ts]

I have searched so many links but nothing has been helped. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are your routes configured ? Try something like this `this.router.navigate(['LoggedinPage']);` where LoggedinPage is the name of the route `{path: '/someURL', name: 'LoggedinPage', component: LoggedinPageComponent},` - You have some errors in the console as well. Did you check them ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want actually implement real backed authentication them in your login function you have call API call with /login where you have to put your real API URL where you can check username and password with your DB and in API call generate response and send back to component file.

Then in your component file you have given full path in your router navigate in there you have to just give /index if you have created router constant in your module file.